# Validation Error in javascript

Tags: javascript

Validation doesn't work correctly. when we fill at any one field of these, it goes to function call

```
if ((name == "") && (uname == "") && (password1 == "") && (password2 == "") && (imei == "")) {
    alert("Enter Necessary Fileld");
} else if (password1 == password2) {
    registerDetails(name, uname, password1, managerId, address1, address2, city, state, country, postcode, number, email, imei, simCard);
} else {
    alert("Password Doesn't match");
}
```

Comment: I guess what you need is an `||` operator instead of `&&` in the `if condition`

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle to explain clearly what you are looking for. However the code above is not correct. As per your code, if all the name, uname etc fields are empty you alert but if one of these fields are filled in with some value, it checks the second condition where it compares the passwords. Since [I assume] the password fields are blank, it satisfies the condition and executes the registerDetails function.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you wanted to use `||` instead of `&&`.

`||` would mean, that any field must be empty to not validate, while `&&` means what all fields must be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
if ((name == "") || (uname == "") || (password1 == "") || (password2 == "") || (imei == "")) {
    alert("Enter Necessary Fileld");
} else if (password1 == password2) {
    registerDetails(name, uname, password1, managerId, address1, address2, city, state, country, postcode, number, email, imei, simCard);
} else {
    alert("Password Doesn't match");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if ((name == "") && (uname == "") && (password1 == "") && (password2 == "") && (imei == "")) {
    alert("Enter Necessary Fileld");
}
```

to this so that it will be executed if anyone of the fields are null.

```
if ((name == "") || (uname == "") || (password1 == "") || (password2 == "") || (imei == "")) {
    alert("Enter Necessary Fileld");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`&&` stands for [conjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction), so **only** when all conditions are true, conjunction is true. Because your conditions check if elements are empty, in fact, you check if no one of these variables are empty.

Change `&&` into `||`, which stands for [disjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction).